# Html form does not send data

Tags: php

I have a form to send an email. It works fine on my local version(I use php -S). But on server when I send form to "email/message" with method POST, it is redirecting me but with method get and I do not have any data in $_GET or $_POST array.

I can get data if I change url from "email/message" to "/". So I guess, problem is in my routing or I have to add something in htaacess. Code looks like that:

**EDIT**
Ok, I think I know where the problem is, so when I send form to "email/message" server is looking for that file then request responds 404 and server is sending request to index.php file(look htaccess) and when server redirect request to index.php data from $_POST array are removed and it do that using get method to index.php not post like in form.

```
//index 

require './Router.php';
require './Request.php';

$router = new Router();

Router::load('./Routes.php')->direct(Request::uri(), Request::method());

class Request
{
    public static function uri()
    {
        return trim(
            parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH), '/'
        );
    }

    public static function method()
    {
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }
}

class Router
{
    protected $routes = [
        'GET' => [],
        'POST' => []
    ];

    public static function load($file)
    {
        $router = new static; 

        require $file;

        return $router; 
    }

    public function get($uri, $controller, $method)
    {
        $this->routes['GET'][$uri] = ['controller' => $controller, 'method' => 
        $method];
    }

    public function post($uri, $controller, $method)
    {
        $this->routes['POST'][$uri] = ['controller' => $controller, 'method' 
        => $method];
    }

    public function direct($uri, $requestType)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes[$requestType])) {
            require 'src/Controllers/'.$this->routes[$requestType][$uri] 
              ['controller']. '.php';
            $controllerName = "App\Controllers\\".$this->routes[$requestType] 
              [$uri]['controller'];
            $controller = new $controllerName();
            $method = $this->routes[$requestType][$uri]['method'];
            $controller->$method();
            return;
        }

        include "./templates/errors/404.html";
    }
}

// My routes

$router->get('', 'IndexController', 'index');
$router->post('email/message', 'MailController', 'sendEmailWithMessage');

.htaccess
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

If somebody can help me I will be grateful.

Comment: i don't see any route for send/email ?

Comment: This seems to use some kind of framework. Can you add the tag for that?

Comment: @ Soufiane Lamnizeh, Sorry my fault, url in form is email/message not send/email.  KIKO Software, I do not use any framework.